# Xcode Real-time Syntax Checking?

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode

I'm new to Xcode and Objective C, but I'm digging my way through the IDE and noticing that it doesn't appear to do live syntax checking.  If I make a typo, I have to build the project before Xcode will even mention that there's a problem.  Worse still - since it's returning compiler errors, it's usually not even the (in)correct line that's highlighted!

Is there a setting that I'm missing, or is that just what I'm stuck with compiling to check for syntax errors?

Comment: What version of XCode are you running? As far as I know, Xcode 4 supports live syntax checking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you're using Xcode 4.*, go to Preferences -> General, select "Enable Live Issues".

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm on 3.2 (My bad for not mentioning that).  Was the feature added in 4.0?

Comment: oops sorry. Yep I think it's not available on pre-Xcode 4 versions.

Answer (score 1):

Select Target from TARGETS Navigator, select Build Settings, LLMV CLL 4.2 - Language > change Precompile Prefix Header setting to "NO", re-open Project (Workspace). It's worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're on the current release of Xcode 4. Despite the 4-ish-ness of its version number, it was a complete rewrite from the previous release, and the early editions of it were sketchy, especially in "code sense" features like syntax highlighting and live error checking.

I've been much happier with it in its last few releases.